# Need Command button to open record ID range using text boxes

Tags: forms, ms-access, button, textbox, range

I have 30 reports to open to file my sales tax based on installs in different areas.  I made a query and report for each area with criteria in each query under PaymentID stating Between FromPayment And ToPayment  My issue is that i have to open each query and enter the ID 30 times.
Can I make a text box range and button to open all reports at once by filling in the text box on a form ONE time. Not sure how to do this. Please help.

Comment: What technology are you using?

Comment: Access with Office 365, newest version

Comment: My Query has criteria set under PaymentID using BETWEEN and criteria under Area that says "101" and next Query "102" and so forth to match the 30 Reports made from each Query. I made a Form with macro Command button that will open all 30 reports but it asks me the parameter each time. I want to put two text boxes on that Form to imput FromPaymentID ToPaymentID I just dont know how to connect them to the button. And if I need to take the BETWEEN statement off of each Query Or if I need some type of Macro to update each Query with the From and To criteria.  t